# Caliburn.micro definition in XAML (cal:) error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

`VS2012` detects an error with my definition of the namespace **"cal:"**, this is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TOP.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="1024" Height="768">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" Background="#FFCB8282" Margin="0,10,0,205"/>

        <ItemsControl x:Name="Items" Margin="0,337,0,0" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Button Content="{Binding DisplayName}"
                             cal:Message.Attach="[Action ActivateItem($this)"  Height="100" Width="100" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I also tried with `xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro"` but the result is the same.

If I execute the application, the Action works well, but the detection of the error disturbs specially with the design preview...

Anybody knows how to fix this error?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. Point your namespace to Caliburn.Micro.Platform

...
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform"
...>

Answer (score 0):

I once got the same kind of error.

If you have added `Caliburn.Micro` as a project to your solution, then please remove the project reference from your main Project and readd the reference to `Calibrun.Micro`

Comment: I have not a separate project "Caliburn.Micro", in my solution just have one project (TOP). I deleted and readded the reference but the error still persists :-(

Comment: @Charleh, sorry for the late response. I added it via NuGet.